# Is it better to prepare for a phd, before pursuing one, while working in industry

Tags: phd, research-process, mathematics, research-undergraduate, independent-researcher

Is it unusual in mathematics to do a PhD in a unrelated area then youre diploma thesis.
Not completely unrelated, as for instance financial mathematics would be to abstract algebra, but such that it would not really build on the diploma thesis.

Sure it would be possible and I'm sure there are lots of people doing that.

But wouldn't that result in much more work, to learn the basics first.

Maybe it is better to work in industry meanwhile you catch up with the basics first.

Sure you can do that also while doing youre phd. But I think this would lengthen the phd unecessary. What do you think?

Comment: The most efficient way to catch up with the basics is while actually doing the PhD. Yes, you can do this, inefficiently, on your own. But what exactly is the benefit supposed to be of spending, say, 3 years in the industry "learning the basics" in your spare time without any feedback and supervision + 3 years doing a PhD vs. 4 years of doing a PhD?

Comment: @AdamPřenosil you exactly get my thought. I thought this way might give me already some work experience on top, such that when Im old the people dont mind cause I already have some work experience

Comment: "when Im old the people dont mind cause I already have some work experience" I don't think I understand what you are saying here, but if your motivation is that you want to have industry experience before you start a PhD, then sure, that sounds to me like a legit reason to go to pursue industry experience. On the other hand, going into industry so that you can use that time to learn, say, the basics of algebraic geometry is something that makes less sense to me.